# Print UIWebView screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, airprint

I have a UIWebView with a graphic generated by Google Charts (javascript rendered)

The screen is not a pdf or png.

Is it possible to capture what's on the screen and send it to AirPrint?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and send that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a screenshot of the webview and send it to AirPrint.

```
// TAKE SCREENSHOT
CGRect myRect = [self.view bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myRect.size);   
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(ctx, myRect);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 1.0);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: +1 For PengOne, this is the right way to print the screen,to get the screenshot.I use the same way.Well ivink without using you are saying this is not possible.You got the answer just implement that dear

Answer (score 3):

Here's the answer translated to Monotouch .NET c#

```
  public static UIImage TakeScreenShot (UIView view)
{
    try
    {
        RectangleF canvasRect = view.Bounds;
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (canvasRect.Size);

        CGContext ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();
        ctx.FillRect (canvasRect);
        view.Layer.RenderInContext (ctx);

        UIImage newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();

        UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();

        return newImage;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function 'UIGetWebViewPrintScreen' should be called after UIWebView.LoadFinished

```
void main()
{
  RectangleF rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  UIWebView = new UIWebView();
  UIImage Img = null;
  string sHtml = "test string";
  WebView.LoadHtmlString(sHtml, null);
  WebView.Frame = rect;
  WebView.LoadFinished += delegate
  {
    if (UIGetWebViewPrintScreen (WebVIew, Img))
    {
      //doing with Img what you want.
    }
  }
}


public bool UIGetWebViewPrintScreen(UIWebView WebView, out UIImage Img)
    {
      bool bSuccess = false;
      //Should be call after event uiWebView.LoadFinished
      UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(WebView.ScrollView.Bounds.Size);
      CGContext cnt = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
      if (cnt != null)
      {
        WebView.Layer.RenderInContext(cnt);
        Img = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        bSuccess = true;
      }
      else
        Img = null;
      UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

      return bSuccess;
    }
```